# Multiple Clickable links in TextView on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, textview

I'm trying to add multiple links in a textview similar to what Google & Flipboard has done below with their **Terms and conditions** AND **Privacy Policy** shown in the screen shot below:

So far I've stumbled on using this approach

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtml);
 textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

where myHtml is a href.

But it doesn't give me control I need e.g to launch a fragment etc.

Any idea how they achieve this in the two examples below?

[image: Flipboard terms and conditions view]

[image: Google terms and conditions view]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#addLinks) (*android.text.Spannable*,*java.util.regex.Pattern*,*java.lang.String*)

```
String termsAndConditions = getResources().getString(R.string.terms_and_conditions);
String privacyPolicy = getResources().getString(R.string.privacy_policy);

legalDescription.setText(
    String.format(
        getResources().getString(R.string.message),
        termsAndConditions,
        privacyPolicy)
);
legalDescription.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Pattern termsAndConditionsMatcher = Pattern.compile(termsAndConditions);
Linkify.addLinks(legalDescription, termsAndConditionsMatcher, "terms:");

Pattern privacyPolicyMatcher = Pattern.compile(privacyPolicy);
Linkify.addLinks(legalDescription, privacyPolicyMatcher, "privacy:");
```

and then you can use the scheme to start an activity for example by adding the scheme in the *AndroidManifest*:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="terms" />
    <data android:scheme="privacy" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you want to do a custom action, you can set the intent-filter to your current activity, which will have a singleTop launchmode.

This will cause [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) to be fired where can make your custom actions:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
 ...
  if (intent.getScheme().equals(..)) {
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: This helps a lot but what if I don't want to start activity  can I handle a click through a listener for the links?

Comment: Important part: The Linkify.addLinks has to be done before tvTermsOfUse.setMovementMethod, otherwise it won't work.

No other settings are necessary in XML.

Comment: The linkify   make the links appear with underscore how to  remove that , to reflect as flipboard this

Comment: the ACTION.view  intent with this  custom scheme will only be within the app or even other can  add intent filter and tap into this (I hope not as this would error prone) @harrane ??

Comment: @harrane Is it possible to set a web url to this Linkify text so that it will open a web page on clicking on the text???

Comment: @harrane How should I change your code so that i call call a webpage "http://myexample.in/termsofservice" on clicking the linkify text "Terms and Conditions" ?? Please help me....

Comment: @KJEjava48 You can handle the intent however you want

Comment: @harrane finally i found the solution.You need to use transformFilter to avoid the linkify text to appending with the weburl as specified in my answer here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803555/android-linkify-text-onclick-is-not-calling-the-web-url/42803875#42803875"

Comment: @KJEjava48 Your case in that question is slightly different, but you could still achieve it with the solution above and launch the browser manually with whatever the url u want. Also, the scheme you are using there is not really a scheme :))

Comment: @harrane I tried with above for my case by using Intent browse = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://myexample.in/termsofservice"));
                startActivity(browse); inside startActivity(Intent intent) {} ,but it doesnt load the weburl that i requested???

Answer (score 109):

### **UPDATE Sept, 2023**

---

I have created a small library around this for Composable. You can simply use the same and save time. Here is the library:
[TermsText_Composable](https://github.com/TusharGogna/TermsText_Composable)

In your **Settings.gradle.kts**, add:

```
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
```

and in your app level **build.gradle.kts**, add:

```
    implementation("com.github.TusharGogna:TermsText_Composable:v1.0.4")
```

---

I think that I'm a little late to share this, but I have achieved the same using [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html).

Simply initialize the `TextView` that you want to add 2 or more listeners and then pass that to the following method that I have created:

```
private void customTextView(TextView view) {
        SpannableStringBuilder spanTxt = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                "I agree to the ");
        spanTxt.append("Term of services");
        spanTxt.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Terms of services Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, spanTxt.length() - "Term of services".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
        spanTxt.append(" and");
        spanTxt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 32, spanTxt.length(), 0);
        spanTxt.append(" Privacy Policy");
        spanTxt.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Privacy Policy Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, spanTxt.length() - " Privacy Policy".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
        view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        view.setText(spanTxt, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
```

And in your XML, use `android:textColorLink` to add custom link color of your choice. Like this:

```
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="TextView"
     android:textColorLink="#C36241" />  //#C36241 - Rust
```

And this looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This works well if the string does not need to be translated

Comment: can also use with localization : multi language just pass string into where text  used. i just done with it  :)

Comment: Yes, it will work. My last comment was for RTL languages.

Comment: marquee doesn't work after applying this, any idea guys?

Comment: @BeeingJk You want to scroll the text?

Comment: @TusharGogna yea seems Spannable doesn't work with Marquee

Comment: @BeeingJk I just tested it. It is working. Can you share what properties  are you using? Let's continue the conversation [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow)

Answer (score 7):

Here's my solution:

**First we need to have clickable links in our TextView:**

1. Here's my TextView in the xml layout, do not add any links handling
   parameters.

   ```
   <TextView
           android:id="@+id/sign_up_privacy"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/terms_and_privacy"/>
   ```
2. In strings file, I added the resource text with  html tags

   ```
   <string name="terms_and_privacy">By signing up you agree to our <a href="terms:">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="privacy:">Privacy Policy.</a></string>
   ```
3. In onCreateView set LinkMovementMethod to the TextView

   ```
   TextView privacyTextView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_privacy);
   privacyTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
   ```

Now the TextView links are clickable.

**Second, We need to Handle these clicks:**

1. In my Manifest file, I added intent-filter for "terms" and "privacy"
   and Single Instance Launch Mode

   ```
   <activity
               android:name=".MyActivity"
               android:launchMode="singleInstance">
               <intent-filter>
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                   <data android:scheme="terms"/>
                   <data android:scheme="privacy"/>
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
   ```
2. In MyActivity, override onNewIntent to catch privacy and terms
   intents

   ```
   @Override
       protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
       {
           if (intent.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase(getString("terms")))
           {
               //handle terms clicked
           }
           else if (intent.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase(getString("privacy")))
           {
               //handle privacy clicked
           }
           else
           {
               super.onNewIntent(intent);
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: it is not working. Log has message ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=terms: (has extras) }

Comment: @sonnv1368, did you override onNewIntent(Intent) in your Activity?

Comment: Anyway I suggest using a SpannableString as a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30365618/1729952

Comment: @Ahmod Baraka: Thank you.

Comment: An improved code for this answer if you want just open a new Activity is to set the manifest <intent-filter> into the destination <activity> you want to open. This way you can avoid the use of "singleInstance" for the current Activity, that may cause some critical problems.

Comment: I like this solution, but there is an issue, if any other app use the same scope "terms" or "privacy", the system will detect that the intent can be opened with two or more apps and will notify the user to choose. It is good to use a rare or "unique" scope for the intent-filter.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this is with string file

In string.xml

```
<string name="agree_to_terms">I agree to the %1$s and %2$s</string>
<string name="terms_of_service">Terms of Service</string>
<string name="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</string>
```

In onCreateView call below method

```
private void setTermsAndCondition() {
    String termsOfServicee = getString(R.string.terms_of_service);
    String privacyPolicy = getString(R.string.privacy_policy);
    String completeString = getString(R.string.agree_to_terms, termsOfServicee,privacyPolicy);
    int startIndex = completeString.indexOf(termsOfServicee);
    int endIndex = startIndex + termsOfServicee.length();
    int startIndex2 = completeString.indexOf(privacyPolicy);
    int endIndex2 = startIndex2 + privacyPolicy.length();
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(completeString);
    ClickableSpan clickOnTerms = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "click on terms of service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue));

        }
    };
    ClickableSpan clickOnPrivacy = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "click on privacy policy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue));

        }
    };
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(clickOnTerms, startIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(clickOnPrivacy, startIndex2, endIndex2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    yourTextView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
    yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Textoo](https://github.com/bluecabin/Textoo), this can be achieved like:

res/values/strings.xml:

```
<resources>
     <string name="str_terms_and_privacy">By signing up you agree to our <a href="terms:">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="privacy:">Privacy Policy.</a></string>
</resources>
```

res/layout/myActivity.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_terms_and_privacy"
    android:text="@string/str_terms_and_privacy"
    />
```

java/myPackage/MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        TextView termsAndPrivacy = Textoo
            .config((TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_terms_and_privacy))
            .addLinksHandler(new LinksHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean onClick(View view, String url) {
                    if ("terms:".equals(url)) {
                        // Handle terms click
                        return true;  // event handled
                    } else if ("privacy:".equals(url)) {
                        // Handle privacy click
                        return true;  // event handled
                    } else {
                        return false;  // event not handled.  continue default processing i.e. launch web browser and display the link
                    }
                }
            })
            .apply();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This approach have the advantages that:

- Keep text externalized as string resource.  Make it easier to localize your app.
- Can handle the click event directly using `LinksHandler` and no need to define additional intent filter
- Simpler and more readable code

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me :

in xml :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_by_continuing_str"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    tools:text="Test msg 1 2, 3"
    android:textColor="@color/translucent_less_white3"
    android:textColorLink="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_privacy_continue" />
```

In strings.xml

```
< string name="by_continuing_str2">< ! [ CDATA[By continuing to use this app, you agree to our <a href="https://go.test.com" style="color:gray"/> Privacy Statement </a> and <a href="https://go.test.com" style="color:gray"/>Services Agreement.]]>< / string>
```

in the activity :

```
TextView tv_by_continuing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_by_continuing);
tv_by_continuing.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.by_continuing_str2)));
tv_by_continuing.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private fun customTextView(view: TextView) {

        //I agree to the Terms of service & Privacy Policy,
        val spanTxt = SpannableStringBuilder(
            "I agree to the ")
        spanTxt.append("Terms of service")
        spanTxt.setSpan(object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
             
                toast("Terms of service link clicked")

            }
        }, spanTxt.length - "Term of services".length, spanTxt.length, 0)
        spanTxt.append(" and")
        spanTxt.append(" Privacy Policy")
        spanTxt.setSpan(object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {

                toast("Privacy Policy link clicked")

            }
        }, spanTxt.length - " Privacy Policy".length, spanTxt.length, 0)
        view.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
        view.setText(spanTxt, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for this would be to use multiple labels. One for each link and one for the text.

```
[TermsOfServiceLabel][andLabel][PrivacyPolicy]
```

Or is it necessary that you only use one label?

Comment: multiple labels for what? The textview? can you elaborate further?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to have multiple links in one TextView and do not know how to do this? Splitting the TextViews leaves you with one link per TextView which should not be a problem.

Comment: I could obviously use 3 different text views for but there are other things to consider such as spacing on different devices, which is why I'm trying to see if there is a way to achieve this with a single view.

Comment: Okay, if you want to use one TextView you can ignore my answer!