# Click on link inside TextView class

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

How can I access to click on 2nd link inside TextView? So far I tried:

```
  AndroidElement d = (AndroidElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Notice']"));
    d.click();
```

And using:

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("com.optimum.rdvr.mobile:id/toc_text"));
```

just clicks on 1st link. And I need to get 2nd link. I want to click on "Mobile Privacy Notice" Any one has suggestion?

[image]

Comment: You have selected parent element so it is hard to tell. Select the link element itself. Try using Appium inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#addLinks)

```
String termsOfUse = getResources().getString(R.string.terms_of_use);
String privacyNotice = getResources().getString(R.string.privacy_notice);

legalDescription.setText(
    String.format(
        getResources().getString(R.string.message),
        termsOfUse,
        privacyNotice )
);

//add the links
Pattern privacyNoticeMatcher = Pattern.compile(privacyNotice);
Linkify.addLinks(legalDescription, privacyNoticeMatcher , "privacy:");
Pattern termsOfUseMatcher = Pattern.compile(termsOfUse);
Linkify.addLinks(legalDescription, termsOfUseMatcher , "termsOfUse:");
```

via [Multiple Clickable links in TextView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720117/multiple-clickable-links-in-textview-on-android)

Comment: But I have access to UI only . I actually test application and not develop it. Any thoughts?