# Multiple ids in the same TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, hyperlink, textview

Is it possible to set multiple id values in the same TextView somehow?

I have a long string with multiple clickable links in it and I want to assign ids to those links so I can fetch them in the code, is that achievable?

I tried putting separate TextView elements in a horizontal LinearLayout, but it cannot be wrapped to another row if it's too long.

Is there some custom element/way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: I think you need something with RecycleView

Comment: @FrancescoBocci Hm, I don't see how is that different to LinearLayout implementation since I don't need scrolling

Comment: Why don't you just set the text to the TextView from the code itself? You can use `SpannableString`.

Comment: Take a look at this question, looks like it's what you are looking for.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/28720117/14327871

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi I could do that, but then how can I set ids to the specific part of the string? That's the issue here, and I don't know if it's even achievable to make something like that

Comment: You can't set multiple ids for a single view, because you will never need to do that. Maybe you can explain more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi I need to have different ids for few links in a long string so that I can automate it in Appium, but if I set only one Id to it, I cannot get different links to check if it works

Comment: May be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720117/multiple-clickable-links-in-textview-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecyclerView` to create list of `TextView` with links. For aligning it correctly, you can use [flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Add dependency in `build.gradle(:app)`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
}
```

and use `FlexboxLayoutManager` with `RecyclerView` as follows:

```
val flexLayoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(activity)
flexLayoutManager.flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW;
flexLayoutManager.justifyContent = JustifyContent.FLEX_START;
recyclerViewTextLinks!!.layoutManager = flexLayoutManager
val flexAdapter = FlexDemoAdapter(listOfTextLinks, onTextLinkClicked)  //onTextLinkClicked for handling link clicks
recyclerViewTextLinks!!.adapter = flexAdapter
```