# Filtering ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT to perform action when phone number detected

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-manifest

I'm trying to code an app to **perform some actions with phone numbers when selected, for example, in Chrome**.

The fact is that I can't figure out how to **configure the filtering** so when selecting text, the activity only appears when a phone has been detected (as Phone and SMS app do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkgby.png. **I want my app to be part of this menu.**)

My actual filter is:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But **this adds the app to the list no matter what the selected text is** (it does not check if it is a phone or not). It should only be allowed if the selected text is a phone number.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28720364/8133524 hope this work for you

Comment: AFAIK, that's not possible with `PROCESS_TEXT`. What you're seeing with the phone and SMS items is likely either a function of that app, or a framework modification by the manufacturer, for example.

Comment: Hey. I tested it and this contextual menu appears at every app that allows to select any text. The smartphone uses "pure" Google. Tested on a emui one and works similar.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "'pure' Google", but it is possible that that's been added to the framework since last I went digging through that part of the source. It's not with `PROCESS_TEXT`, though, as those items are added to the end of the menu, and the code that assembles them doesn't do any checks as to what the selected text is.

Comment: Just FYI, that does seem to have been added in Oreo (API level 26), but it's a special item named `textAssist` that just does that one thing, and is not customizable.

Comment: Is there a way to provide custom logic to the intent filter?

Comment: My point was that, if I can implement the logic for evaluating if the intent content (the selected text, provided as text/plain) is or isn't a phone number in the intent filter somehow, then the filter could be effective for my purpose.

Comment: In reviewing this post, I see now that my last couple of comments were vague and confusing. My apologies. Let me clarify: that `<intent-filter>` in your manifest is basically a read-only label. No code in your app executes when that element is read and analyzed by the system. It simply creates an `IntentFilter` object from it and does some comparisons, so there's no point where you would be able to alter that with your own code. Also, your app doesn't see the actual text until it's delivered on the `Intent`, so you wouldn't be able to check that yet anyway. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Thanks Mike! Yeah, it is clearer for me know. Even if it's not possible I appreciate you help in this. As you might have noticed, I am a complete noob.

Comment: @JMorrison Please update if you got the answer i am also trying this .